# Combine rows only if two cells in two different rows are equal in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-forms, google-apps

I have a google form that starts with a Starter page which consists of one text entry that reads "Client's name", and under it is a multiple choice section with the options "Shirt" and "Socks". Pressing next when "Shirt" is activated brings you to a new section, in which you choose the style of shirt. Same happens when you press next with "Socks" activated.

[image]

I set it up this way because It's more user friendly, and I'm adamant that it stays like this.

The form's synced to a sheet, which has 5 columns:
Timestamp, Client's name, Product, Type of shirt and Type of sock

[image]

As you can see on the picture, there are 3 entries:
John, who wants an orange shirt.
Marie, who also wants an orange shirt.
Then another entry for John, that also wants an Orange sock.

My goal is to do the following:
by looking at the client's name and the timestamp, deduce that those can be grouped into the same order, because if two orders are placed in the same day, it means that its probably the same order, thus should be grouped as such so that it may be easier to read.
So instead of having two entries for John, it would be reduced to a single entry which says that John wants both an Orange shirt and an Orange Sock. (This all in a sheet separate from the one linked to the form). This is because, as I said before, I want different orders from same dates combined, but only if its from the same date. If it's from a different date, it's a different order.

It would end up looking like this.
Two columns: "Client's name" and "Order".
Two entries: John's, which has "Orange shirt + Orange socks", and Marie's, which only has "Orange shirt".

[image]

I wanna clarify that I want it this way so that orders from different days *would* repeat, because in the case I'm working with that would mean that its a completely new order.

I've got the joining of both items covered, only problem I have is that I can't find a way to verify that both values are the same before.
After looking around for a long while, I've found a couple of functions that may be helpful. `UNIQUE` (Which shows repeating names only once) and `FILTER`, which I believe is the way to go, but I can't think of how to make it work.
Am I making a mess when there's actually an easier way to think this through?

As asked, here's a link to the form: https://forms.gle/tYTW86LGZUWpTSoZ8

And here's a link to the sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IrE4OCXRkDI63MGpUMJd8_nJlGZxP5-Jf14q6v2aX04/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Do you exclusively want a Google Sheets formula answer or would you also be opened to an [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) answer?

Comment: Please share a test form and its sheet (with public access) including your progress to this point.

Comment: @marikamitsos I added the links to the bottom, I did not make much progress though.

Comment: @MateoRandwolf I prefer to do it through a formula, but I'm not totally against the idea of doing a script instead. However, I know little to nothing about Google Apps Script

Comment: Hi ! I can see from your sheet that you have a "partial solution" ```==arrayformula( 
  query( 
    { 
      "Date", 'Form Responses 1'!B1:J1; 
       iferror(datevalue('Form Responses 1'!A2:A)), 'Form Responses 1'!B2:J 
     }, 
     "select Col1, Col2, Col3, max(Col4), max(Col5), max(Col6), max(Col7), max(Col8), sum(Col9), sum(Col10) 
      where Col3 is not null 
      group by Col1, Col2, Col3", 
  1 ) 
)```. What is this formula not satisfying in your case scenario? What else do you want to achieve that does not accomplish this formula?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up asking for help in the Docs Editor Help google forum, and my problem got mostly solved by someone on their team, here it is:

```
=arrayformula( 
  query( 
    { 
      "Date", 'Form Responses 1'!B1:J1; 
       iferror(datevalue('Form Responses 1'!A2:A)), 'Form Responses 1'!B2:J 
     }, 
     "select Col1, Col2, Col3, max(Col4), max(Col5), max(Col6), max(Col7), max(Col8), sum(Col9), sum(Col10) 
      where Col3 is not null 
      group by Col1, Col2, Col3", 
  1 ) 
)
```

The link to the thread in question is [here](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/79216912?hl=en#)